# How i choose rows, for 5 different string?

Tags: sas

I have a data set of 5 columns. the 5th is authors name. 
I want to choose rows for 5 different authors names. here is my script, but it's doesn't work and i don't know why.

```
  FILENAME ex2 URL "http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~liadshek/Books.txt" ;
  DATA ex2;
  INFILE ex2 firstobs=2;
  INPUT year words copies numberBooks annual author$;
  RUN;
  DATA data5 ;
  SET ex2 ;
  IF (author ~= 'H.A')then delete;* OR (author ~= 'H.H') OR (author ~= 'E.E') OR (author        ~= 'E.D') OR (author ~= 'D.Y') then delete;
  RUN;
```

How i choose rows, for 5 different string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To try this:

```
DATA data5;
SET ex2;
WHERE author in ('H.A', 'H.H', 'E.E', 'E.D', 'D.Y');
RUN;
```

It works correctly on my side..

Comment: I wrote this: `WHERE author in ('"X.C"', '"R.F"', '"M.D.F"', '"V.E"', '"H.A"')`;... and now it's work. Thanks!!